# Yaw pitch rotation issues

Tags: math, rotation, game-development

am coding some stuff which should intercept target correctly like turret,cannon.

All calculated correctly but while enemy is moving to left or right side of screen (also up and down) my bot cant shoot them correctly, center is fine. Here little example whats happens with wrong yaw issue, same with pitch https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYGNV.png

Mission is save bot rotation as is, and fix missfire issues.

As main concept i taken camera position and enemy center

```
Vector2 Rotate(Vector3 Calc)
{
        Vector2 coord;
        float Yaw = (float)(atan2(Calc.y, Calc.x)) * 180.0f / M_PI;
        float Pitch = (float)(atan2(Calc.z, sqrtf(Calc.x * Calc.x + Calc.y * Calc.y))) * 180.0f / M_PI;

        coord.x = Pitch;
        coord.y = Yaw;
        return coord;
}

Vector3 Diff = Target - Bot;
Vector2 Angle = Rotate(Diff);
```

Comment: are you using Unity?

Comment: Not, ue4, but welcomed any crossing solution